# CGRect and utesting

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, core-graphics

I am trying to add unit tests to my iPhone project in Xcode.  Everything works, its great.  Except when I am adding a class.m that uses CGRect (or other structs, CGPoint etc) to the unit test target (under "Compile Sources") - I am getting a compilation error: "'CGRect' undeclared (first use in this function)".  I tried messing with my unit test target in various ways, but so far I haven't been able to get past this.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's undeclared, you haven't included the CoreGraphics header file:

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is obvious in hindsight.  When the class in question is built as part of the "regular" app target, everything must be working fine because other classes import UIKit.h.  However none of the classes built as part of my test target have that import and so GCRect wasn't visible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the CoreGraphics framework to your unit testing target. In your project, under Frameworks, right-click on CoreGraphics.framework and select "Get Info". Click the "Targets" button at the top of the info window, and check the box next to your unit testing target.

Comment: hmmmmm, I already have it as a dependency.  I added it by double-clicking on my testing target, and then adding it under "Linked Libraries".  Just to make sure I removed it, and added it the way you described, but, not surprisingly, that didn't make a difference.